# Text going off the page in Latex Document

Tags: tables, line-breaking

I am hoping someone can help me. The text in the achievement section is going off the page and not breaking onto the new page.

```
\section {Achievements}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
Sep 2015 - Current:& 
\textsc Working alongside the University to encourage the participation in sporting activities within the schools of Computer Science and Mathematics
\end{tabular}
```

What is the solution to preventing this from happening?

Thanks

Comment: **OT:** somehow this looks lie a *curriculum vitae*. Do you know that there is a special document type? https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Curriculum_Vitae  http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/curricula-vitae

Answer (score 1):

By default, no wrapping of text occurs within a `l`eft-, `r`ight or `c`entre-aligned `tabular` cell. Instead, you can use a `p`aragraph alignment, or perhaps [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx)'s `X`-alignment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\section{Achievements}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{rl}
  Sep 2015 - Current: & 
    Working alongside the University to encourage the participation in sporting 
    activities within the schools of Computer Science and Mathematics
\end{tabular}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ @{} r X @{} }
  Sep 2015 - Current: & 
    Working alongside the University to encourage the participation in sporting 
    activities within the schools of Computer Science and Mathematics \\

  Sep 2015 - Current: & \raggedright\arraybackslash
    Working alongside the University to encourage the participation in sporting 
    activities within the schools of Computer Science and Mathematics \\

  Sep 2015 - Current: & \RaggedRight
    Working alongside the University to encourage the participation in sporting 
    activities within the schools of Computer Science and Mathematics
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```